# ES6: import many files

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a script that imports a lot of AMD modules and calls an initialization method on each one:

```
define(['underscore', './mod0', ..., './modN'], function (_) {
    _.each(_.toArray(arguments).slice(1), function (m) {
        init(m);
    });
});
```

I need to switch to ES6 import syntax and I am trying to figure out if it is possible to import modules from a list, in a manner similar to my AMD code. I want to avoid insanity like:

```
import mod0 from './mod0';
...
import modN from './modN';

init(mod0);
...
init(modN);
```

Any advice on how this can be accomplished?
thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to import modules from a list?

No, not without explicitly invoking your module loader (whichever that is). There is no way to do this using `import` declarations.

> Any advice on how this can be accomplished?

`eval` could probably do it :-)

I would recommend using two modules:

```
// index.js
export mod0 from './mod0';
…
export modN from './modN';
```

```
// init-all.js
import * as modules from './index'; // enumerable namespace

for (var moduleIdentifier in modules)
    init(modules[moduleIdentifier]);
```

You could potentially do the same with only a single module (that imports itself as a module namespace object), but that surely would be real insanity.