# Is it possible to add ES6 imports straight onto an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following example:

```
import ThingA from './ThingA';
import ThingB from './ThingB';
// ... import more things

const things = {
  ThingA,
  ThingB,
  // ... add more things to object
};
```

This code works fine, but each item being imported needs to be specified twice (once to import, once to add it to the object). Is there a way to remove this duplication?

I've taken a look at the [import docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import), but the syntax doesn't seem to support anything for this use case.

Comment: import/export wasn't designed to be dynamic, unfortunately (IMO it's one of the worse parts of ES6 design).

Comment: Each item being imported isn't "specified twice". The `import` imports it, then you actually *use* it.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: it makes static analysis a lot easier and reliable.

Comment: @FelixKling I know that. I don't like this choice.

Comment: Why do you need to place your imports in an object at all? This seems like an XY Problem.

Comment: @Mathletics I need to be able to iterate over them

Comment: @rouan: You'll want to have a look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35439066/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to `import` directly into an object property or to use the `import` in different expressions than standard one:

```
import <ImportClause> from <ModuleSpecifier>
```

Check [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports) the exact import specification.

Comment: Hu ? There are other possible syntaxes. See the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import#Syntax

Comment: @DenysSéguret I mean generally. It's not the case to list them all. :D

Comment: I'd recommend [this](http://wesbos.com/javascript-modules/) reading